# Making my buttons right and left instead of stacking?

Tags: html, css

So i am trying to get my buttons to show up left or right of another button, and instead of on top/bottom of the button. I'm new to all of this and would love to figure this out.

Here is my code, what could i apply to it that would make them stack left/right?

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="submit" value="Contact me">
</form>
```

Comment: You must use some css to achiev that, using solely html, quite every element (not all, but most) are "block elements".

Comment: Which buttons? I only see one in your code.

Answer (score 1):

there is a lot of ways to do this, but you can try `float` css property as follow:

```css
input[type="submit"]{

  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}

input[type="button"]{

  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
<input type="submit" value="Contact me">
<input type="button" value="another button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try researching the `float` property in CSS [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp). You can alter the visual flow of your HTML document by doing so, e.g.

```css
#button1 {
    float: right;
}
#button2 {
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 50%;">
       <input id="button1" type="button" value="button 1">
       <input id="button2" type="button" value="button 2">
       <input id="button3" type="button" value="button 3">
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your problem correctly, you meant to say that you wanted to get the buttons in this form side to each other instead of one below the other. According to me, when you will add another button in this form, it will appear at the side of the first button only. But don't give `<br/>` tag between buttons and even do not put them into the separate `<div>` tags.
Here is the sample of my code I did for you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button Left/Right</title>
    <link src="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>       //add this line if you want to add css otherwise ignore this line and remove from code
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Contact me">            //observe I have given class to the buttons  
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Contact me Button 2">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In case if it is not working, then create the following style.css file inside the directory where you have the current html file. And in the style.css file add following lines:

```
.btn{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The first HTML code worked, but how do i add a link to each button? is my issue.

Comment: We can put the buttons in the <a> tag and put the href attribute to the link wherever we want. Like this,
`<a href="link_to_redirect"><input type="button" value="button" /></a>`
Points to note:
1) If you want to redirect user to a link on successful submission of form, then you can put that link into the action parameter of <form tag>
like this `<form action="link_to_redirect">` and do not put the submit button into the <a> tag
2) And put all other buttons into <a> tag and redirect them wherever you want by using href attribute